# How to create a view can resizeed by it's subviews?

Tags: ios

I have a view:

```
@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) UILabel  *titleLabel;

@end
```

The UILabel can determine its frame with contents. I want to make MyView autoresize when text of the titlelabel changed.

I have implemented this method in MyView, which can determine size of view with autolayout feature:

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGSize size = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    CGSize labelSize = [_titleLabel intrinsicContentSize];
    size.height = labelSize.height;
    size.width = labelSize.width + 50;

    return size;
}
```

And this method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGSize mysize = [self intrinsicContentSize];
    CGRect frame = _titleLabel.frame;
    // center in the view
    frame.origin.x = (mysize.width - [_titleLabel intrinsicContentSize].width) / 2;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size.width = [_titleLabel intrinsicContentSize].width;
    frame.size.height = [_titleLabel intrinsicContentSize].height;
    _titleLabel.frame = frame;
    _titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

I think it is not a good idea, because the method layoutSubviews will be called several times. And it cannot resize the view when I set the text here:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // the view can be resized
    _avartarView.titleLabel.text = @"asdfjkl;!@#$%^&*()";
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // the view cannot be resize
    _avartarView.titleLabel.text = @"haha";
}
```

Are there any solution?

I have tried this with auto layout, but it does not work. The height of avartarView is still zero.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_avartarView = [[PPAvartarView alloc] init];
_avartarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
_avartarView.titleLabel.text = @"foobar";
_avartarView.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
_avartarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview: _avartarView];
[self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|-50-[_avartarView]" options: 0 metrics: nil views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_avartarView)]];
[self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-100-[_avartarView]" options: 0 metrics: nil views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_avartarView)]];
_avartarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

@end


@implementation PPAvartarView

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
_titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self addSubview: _titleLabel];
[self addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-10-[_titleLabel]-10-|" options: 0 metrics: nil views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_titleLabel)]];
[self addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: _titleLabel attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier: 1 constant: 0]];
return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Auto layout can handle this very well... Have you ever considered  using it? (If your project can support it)

Comment: I am using auto layout. I think auto layout does not support resize view with its content size. I have to add a height contraint to the view.

Comment: If you pin the subview to the top and bottom of the superview using autolayout then the superview will be constrained to the size of the subview

Comment: Thank you, but it does no work with my code.